# jquery make enter button submit form

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form that looks like this:

```
<form action="#" name="submit" method="post">
        <input name="zip" id="zip" type="text" value="" class="zip-start" />
        <div class="form-submit"><a href="" id="zipformSubmit" rel="zipformSubmit" class="zipformSubmit">Submit</a></div>
    </form>
```

I have JS that looks like this:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a[rel=zipformSubmit]").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
         var zip = $('#zip').val();
         if (zip.length < 5) { alert("Please enter a valid zip code"); return false;};
        $.colorbox({href: "/ppc/form.htm?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600}); 
    }); 
    });  
</script>
```

The problem is that the user can only submit this form by clicking on the submit button.  Any ideas on how i can adjust the js so that the enter button also submits the form?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the 'enter button'? It's not clear above.

Comment: @JJ, enter key on your keyboard! :)

Comment: @rob melino, did I answer your question completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as well jQuery's [`submit` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method to listen for an form submit from clicking enter.

```
<script> 
    function submitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var zip = $('#zip').val();
        if (zip.length < 5) { alert("Please enter a valid zip code"); return false;};
        $.colorbox({href: "/ppc/form.htm?zip=" + zip, iframe:true, innerWidth:800, innerHeight:600});
    }

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            submitHandler(e);
        });

        $("a[rel=zipformSubmit]").click(function(e) { 
            submitHandler(e);
        }); 
    });  
</script>
```

You should however change this `$('form')` to something more specific. Add an id for the form and it should be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$(...).submit()`?